# How to call functions only after the completion of the previous

Tags: javascript, image, function, promise, async-await

Im stuck in trying to get imageData of base64 image. I have 2 functions, and the problem is that second function starts before first ends.

I have 2 functions

```
frame.restoreImageDataForLayers();
frame.changeResultLayer();
```

first - load image on a page and then change variable 'layers.data' to imageData of that loaded image.
second - work with imageData of image.

```
restoreImageDataForLayers() {
    this.layers.forEach((item) => {
      const layer = item;
      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      const image = new Image();
      image.onload = function drawImg() {
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        layer.data = context.getImageData(0, 0, layer.canvasSize, layer.canvasSize).data;
console.log('FIRST', layers.data');
      };
      image.src = layer.data;

    });
  }

changeResultLayer() {
    console.log('SECOND', this.layers[0].data);
  }
```

And then i have 
second console log before
first console log
and my another code that must work with  imageData - crash. 
How to fix that?

Answer (score -1):

You will want to convert `restoreImageDataForLayers` into a function that returns a promise, whose promise only resolves when the operations in the function complete.

```
restoreImageDataForLayers() {
  const layerPromises = this.layers.map(item => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      // All your canvas-image code here...

      image.onload = function(){

        // Your onload code here

        // Then resolve the promise for this item
        resolve()
      }
    })
  })

  return Promise.all(layerPromises)
}
```

To do that, you need to wrap your image loading procedure in a promise. Use `array.map()` to create an array of these promises, one for each item. Then use `Promise.all()` to create that one promise that resolves only when all of the promises in the array resolves.

To call this function, you simply do this:

```
frame.restoreImageDataForLayers().then(() => {
  frame.changeResultLayer();
});
```

Or if the caller is in an `async` function, do this:

```
async thatWrapperFunction(){
  await frame.restoreImageDataForLayers();
  frame.changeResultLayer();
}
```